# LibGDX - a simple water background

Tags: java, background, libgdx, effect

I'm working at a game, where the action is underwater.
I want to make something very simple that goes on top of every texture in the game, to simulate the underwater effect.

Using just a photo with transparency will do this
[image]
But this is not that good looking, and it feels beter without it.
I want to make something similar to water texture from the game, but I want to make the little waves moving, so it gives an underwater aspect.
Maybe something like - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UlrGi7jwmIM, but without thoose complex movements, just simple waves.

I tried to use libgdx particle editor, but for a simple flame (the default one), it eats a lot of my FPS, and anyways, I don't need a complex effect just a simple one, that can cover my 800x480 game screen, and gives the effect of playing underwater.

Something like http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DA_dU_46aIc , but 2D.
Does anyone got some ideeas?

Comment: Use a transparent image that more closely resembles the effect you're going for? I can't tell whether you're already doing this from the screenshot, but moving the photo to create a parallax effect would probably help you out quite a bit.

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/WaterRipples.java
check this out...

Comment: If I move the photo there will be a moving effect, but the waves are not changing, and is not looking that good..

Comment: @sandeep i don't need something that complex

Comment: its not that complicated ,u need not to edit any thing in this code

Comment: And how can I add it to my screen?

Comment: I think you could do that with shaders scripts

Comment: @user2223062 no , I just put an image with transparency on top ..